# От какого класса лучше породить Viewer

Tags: qt, c++

В общем, нужен специальный `Viewer`, использующий `QPixmap` как источник данных.
Схема классическая: Viewer <-> Табличная модель  <-> QPixmap.

Так как нужны анимации, решил реализовывать на QGrapicsScene, но тут встал вопрос, на чем лучше это сделать:

На ***QGraphicsItem*** и потом встраивать в QGraphicsScene или на ***QGraphicsScen*** и потом только отображать его в QGraphicsView?

Comment: @Expert ♦♦

А с чего вы взяли, что у меня C++? :)

У меня с таким же успехом мог быть Python или любой другой язык с поддержкой классического ООП и Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, сделал связку *QPixmap* <-> *QGraphicsScene* <-> *QGraphicsRectItem*.
*QGraphicsScene* работает с табличной моделью, которая присасывается к *QPixmap*, и затем *QGraphicsScene* отображает на *QGraphicsRectItem* данные с *QPixmap*, полученные через модель.

При изменении данных на *QGraphicsRectItem* через ту же модельку все обновленные данные гонятся на *QPixmap*. Классическая реализация принципов

> Данные <-> Модель <-> Представление